# Access Denied when trying to set formdigestsettings in a list event receiver even when logged in as Farm Administrator account

Tags: event-receivers, access-denied

I am trying to set the formdigestsettings to false within an event receiver (sharepoint 2010). So far I have tried to a) run the code with elevated privileges

```
public override void ListAdded(SPListEventProperties properties)
{
   SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
   {
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.SiteId))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPWebApplication webApp = site.WebApplication;
                webApp.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
   }
}
```

I am getting Access Denied on this line-

`webApp.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = false;`

b) create the SPSite using the Farm Administrator account usertoken

```
public override void ListAdded(SPListEventProperties properties)
{
   properties.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
   SPUser FarmAdminAccount = properties.Web.EnsureUser(@"DOMAIN\farm.account");
   properties.Web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

   using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.SiteId, FarmAdminAccount.UserToken ))
   {
       using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
       {
           SPWebApplication webApp = site.WebApplication;
           webApp.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = false;
       }
   }
}
```

In this case also the code gave an Access Denied error on this line- `webApp.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = false;`

c) lastly I tried to login to the sharepoint website using the Farm Administrator account and password and then also I got the Access Denied error.

IN each of the 3 cases when i checked the web.CurrentUser.LoginName it always displayed as SHAREPOINT\system.

Can somebody please give some ideas?

---

----------------------UPDATE------------------------------

Hi

What I am actually trying to do is to attach the OOTB sharepoint workflow [Approval Sharepoint - 2010] to each and every document library that ever gets created. To accomplish this  I created a List Added event reciever and put this code in it -

```
public override void ListAdded(SPListEventProperties properties)
{
   SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
   {  
       SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest();

        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(properties.SiteId))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                try
                {
                    base.ListAdded(properties);
                    if (currentList is SPDocumentLibrary)
                    {
                        SPDocumentLibrary docLib = (SPDocumentLibrary)properties.List;


                        //workflows need a tasks and history list. Here we assume they exist
                        SPList taskList = web.Lists["Tasks"];
                        SPList historyList = web.Lists["Workflow History"];

                        //loop through the workfows in the web and grab the one we want by name
                        SPWorkflowTemplate wfTemp = null;
                        foreach (SPWorkflowTemplate wt in web.WorkflowTemplates)
                        {
                            if (wt.Name == "Approval - SharePoint 2010")
                            {
                                wfTemp = wt;
                                Common.AddToLog(web, "Found " + wt.Name + " in current web " +
                                web.Url, false);
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        //Now add the workflow to the doc library
                        SPWorkflowAssociation workFlow = SPWorkflowAssociation.CreateListAssociation(wfTemp, wfTemp.Name, taskList, historyList);

                        workFlow.AllowManual = true;
                        workFlow.AutoStartChange = false;
                        workFlow.AutoStartCreate = true;
                        workFlow.AssociationData = null;

                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                        web.ValidateFormDigest();
                        docLib.WorkflowAssociations.Add(workFlow);                                

                        docLib.EnableModeration = true;

                        docLib.Update();
                        web.Update();
                        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                finally
                {
                    web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
                }
            }
        }
   });
}
```

I was getting this error -

The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.

at this line

`docLib.WorkflowAssociations.Add(workFlow);`

To resolve that error I did some research and founds some blogs where it was recommended to set the FormDigestSettings of the webapplication to false. But that did not work because I was getting the Access Denied error.

Does anybody have any suggestion for the security error. It seems like a very common thing to do (i.e. attach a workflow to a sharepoint List, don't know why I should be having so much trouble with this)

Answer (score 1):

```
public override void ListAdded(SPListEventProperties properties)
{
    SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest();

    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()     
    {         
         using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url))         
         {             
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())            
            {                
               //do what you want here
            }
        }
   }
}
```

> If the method that is passed to the RunWithElevatedPrivileges method
>   includes a write operation, either of the
>   SPUtility.ValidateFormDigest() or SPWeb.ValidateFormDigest() methods
>   should be called before a call is made to RunWithElevatedPrivileges.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sputility.validateformdigest(v=office.14).aspx

any reason why you want to turn it off? the above method will handle it for you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to run in a "List Added" event receiver: that means that the code is executed at the scope of a site collection/web site.

The property you are trying to change, *"FormDigestSettings"*, is defined on the *SPWebApplication* object. You basically need to change a web application level setting from a simple site context - and that is blocked by default on SharePoint 2010.

SharePoint 2010 introduced a new security setting called "RemoteAdministratorAccessDenied" - this setting has the effect to block any attempt to modify a web application property from a site collecton or web site scope. To quote Microsoft

> *"This feature explicitly blocks any modifications to the objects inheriting from SPPersistedObject in the Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration namespace and does not allow the content web applications to update the configuration database"*

[related kb article [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2564009)]

You have two options here:

1. Refactor your application logics so that you don't need to change that property from inside the site collection. If you could for example move the setting to a web application scoped feature it should work.
2. Disable the security setting. The knowledge base article that I linked provides a PowerShell script to do that. Be aware that doing this is not suggested in a production environment because you would actually disable one of the security layers provided by SharePoint to block potentially dangerous code.